# Jenkins rest api for junit result upload to specific job

Tags: curl, jenkins, junit, automated-tests

I have been trying to POST Junit output.xml to a specific testReort job it returns **Not found** error.

I have tried all combination methods described below, but no success.

1. Does Jenkins supports POST/PUT operation to upload testReport to
   specific job?
2. If not how do i do this task?

> curl --silent --show-error --netrc --header 'Content-Type:
>   application/xml' -X POST --data-binary @/home/test/Desktop/output.xml
>   http://username:token@test.com:8080/job/xx/job/xx_test/job/mytest/1/testReport/
>
> curl --silent --show-error --netrc --header 'Content-Type:
>   application/xml' -X PUT --data-binary @/home/test/Desktop/output.xml
>   http://username:token@test.com:8080/job/xx/job/xx_test/job/mytest/1/testReport/
>
> curl --silent --show-error --netrc --header 'Content-Type:
>   application/xml' -X POST --data-binary @/home/test/Desktop/output.xml
>   --user username:password http://test.com:8080/job/xx/job/xx_test/job/mytest/1/testReport/

Thank you very much, your support much appreciated.

Comment: did you tried exectuing the curl command in the `Execute shell` step of the build actions of your job?

Comment: I tried it on Linux machine

Comment: No. I am asking did you try and put this under the Execute shell option in the build actions when you configure a Freestyle project on Jenkins.?

Comment: Yes i am using.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't alter the test results after a build has been completed. There is no API for this.

You should use the [JUnit plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit) during a build to process the results of JUnit XML files that you have.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Junit plugin to upload output.xml for each pipeline, the major problem some time my build crashed in middle, the job execution may take more than 3 days, practically i can't re run, if that is the situation i am planning upload a manual output.xml to respective job.